# Elliptic Curve Point at Infinity

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, cryptography, ecdsa

Let's take into account the Bitcoin curve. My questions are:

1. What exactly is the "point at infinity"?
2. Is there more than one "point at infinity"
3. How can I identify if my EC generated x and y are the "point of infinity"?
4. Is there a way to calculate the "point of infinity"?

Comment: check out this chapter from a great book called Programming Bitcoin by Jimmy Song. The very last part talks about the point of infinity you're interested in. https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin/blob/master/ch02.asciidoc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What exactly is the "point at infinity"?

It's a point that is added to the points on the curve. Together they form a group. It has the following properties:

- (x,y) + (x,-y) = infinity
- (x,y) + infinity = (x,y)
- infinity + (x,y) = (x y)

In other words, the point at infinity is the identity element of the addition in the group. Therefore some people write the point at infinity as "0".

> Is there more than one "point at infinity"

Just one.

> How can I identify if my EC generated x and y are the "point of infinity"?

The point at infinity is not on the curve, so it does not have x or y coordinates. It appears whenever a point is added to its own negation (for which the normal addition rule has no answer).

> Is there a way to calculate the "point of infinity"?

It simply is "the point at infinity", there is nothing to be calculated about it.

Comment: But when I am deriving child public keys from a parent public key there is a step which is if Ki is the point at infinity the resulting key is invalid, I still miss how to figure it out.

Comment: Ki is the sum of point(...) and Kpar. I've given the rules above: if those two have identical coordinates, except the y coordinate is negated, the result is the point at infinity.

Comment: I got it, so if x of Ki = x of point(...)+Kpar and y of Ki = -y of point(...)+Kpar so it is the point at infinity... Greattt

Comment: The point of infinity DOES have coordinates because IT IS on the curve. It is when the point on the curve is on y=0. To know x just do the math. It is called the point of infinity because at this point, the tangent is a totally vertical line which means it has an "infinite" slop.

Comment: @OscarSerna That's nonsense, sorry. The point is on the curve if you're using projective or Jacobian coordinates, but in affine coordinates there is no (x,y) that corresponds to it.

Comment: @OscarSerna For example on the (very small) curve y^2 = x^3 + 8 over GF(97), there is a point on the curve with coordinates (27, 0). It is however not the point at infinity.